# UFT/QTP System.InvalidCastException Error

Tags: testing, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft, uft14

Need some help please. I am trying to execute a UFT test via a vb script through a jenkins pipeline. The test executes and runs fine 3/4 times, on the instance where it doesn't run I get the below warning errors which require the user to press continue to run the test.

```
"Exception of type: System.InvalidCastException. Source: Northwoods.GoWPF. 
Occured in System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object] 
an(System.Object) method
Exception message is: Unable to cast object of type 'Northwoods.GoXam.Group' HP.Utt.Controls.FlowCanvas.FlowCanvas.FlowCanvasItem`1[HP.QTP.BackEndServices.Q tpItemsIfs.IActionCallGraph]"

"Exception of type: System.Windows.Media.Animation.AnimationException. 
Source: PresentationCore. Occured in Void 
OnCurrentTimeInvalidated(System.Object, System.EventArgs) method
Exception message is: Cannot animate the 'Location' property on a 
'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' using a 
'System.Windows.Media.Animation.PointAnimation'. For details see the inner 
exception."
```

Full log;

```
 Exception of type: System.Windows.Media.Animation.AnimationException. Source: PresentationCore. Occured in Void OnCurrentTimeInvalidated(System.Object, System.EventArgs) method
Exception message is: Cannot animate the 'Location' property on a 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' using a 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.PointAnimation'. For details see the inner exception.
Exception trace is:    at System.Windows.Media.Animation.AnimationStorage.OnCurrentTimeInvalidated(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Clock.FireEvent(EventPrivateKey key)
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Clock.RaiseAccumulatedEvents()
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.TimeManager.RaiseEnqueuedEvents()
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.TimeManager.Tick()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.AnimatedRenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Exception of type: System.InvalidCastException. Source: Northwoods.GoWPF. Occured in System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object] #an(System.Object) method
Exception message is: Unable to cast object of type 'Northwoods.GoXam.Group' to type 'HP.Utt.Controls.FlowCanvas.FlowCanvas.FlowCanvasItem`1[HP.QTP.BackEndServices.QtpItemsIfs.IActionCallGraph]'.
Exception trace is:    at Northwoods.GoXam.Model.GraphLinksModel`4.#an(Object #Y7)
   at Northwoods.GoXam.Group.get_MemberNodes()
   at Northwoods.GoXam.Group.#zt()
   at Northwoods.GoXam.Group.#Dj(Boolean #36)
   at Northwoods.GoXam.Part.InvalidateRelationships(String #I5, Boolean #36)
   at Northwoods.GoXam.Node.#Wj()
   at Northwoods.GoXam.Node.#0j(DependencyObject #73, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs #0Y)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.AnimationStorage.OnCurrentTimeInvalidated(Object sender, EventArgs args)

SharpDevelop Version : 4.1.3.0-UFT_14-00000000
.NET Version         : 4.0.30319.42000
OS Version           : Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0
Current culture      : English (United States) (en-US)
Running under WOW6432, processor architecture: x86-64
Terminal Server Session
Working Set Memory   : 377436kb
GC Heap Memory       : 49019kb


An unexpected error occurred.

Click ‘OK’ to close this message. You may be able to continue working, 
but note that this workflow may cause the error to occur again.
Click ‘Details’ to display technical details on this error which may help 
you solve the problem, or can be used when contacting customer support.
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: If it runs a few times and then hits this issue, it seems likely that the data being supplied to the failing issue contains something invalid.  Check your data is of the correct type as the exception is telling you it can't cast from one type to another.  It also says "for details see the inner exception", which would help, as would the code in the script itself.  Right now all you have provided is an exception trace and that's not enough to narrow down a specific issue.

Comment: are you using the HPE Automation Tools plugin or something else? This seems to be an exception of the UFT IDE itself, so if you use custome code, you may just be running UFT in wrong mode.